# how to randomly label with ggplot and geom_text_repel?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm trying to draw a four quadrant chart with dataset `mtcars` with variable `mpg` and `drat`.
Here's my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

data = mtcars[,c(1,5)]

# Rename the columns
colnames(data) = c('x', 'y')

# Calculate mean values
mean_x = mean(data$x)
mean_y = mean(data$y)

# Create a new variable to indicate the quadrant
data$class = ifelse(data$x < mean_x & data$y < mean_y, 3,
                            ifelse(data$x < mean_x & data$y >= mean_y, 2,
                                   ifelse(data$x >= mean_x & data$y < mean_y, 4, 1)))

data$class = factor(data$class)

ggplot(data,aes(x=x, y = y)) + geom_point(size=2,aes(color = class)) + 
ggtitle("four quadrant chart") + theme_classic() + 
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 20, face = "bold"), 
axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=1, vjust=1, size = 10),
axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10),axis.title.x = element_text(size = 20),
axis.title.y = element_text(size = 20), legend.position = c(0.9,0.15), 
legend.title = element_blank(), legend.text=element_text(size=15)) + 
xlab(colnames(data)[1]) + ylab(colnames(data)[2]) + 
geom_text_repel(aes(color = class, label = rownames(data)),max.overlaps = 12,size = 4) + 
geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(y)),linetype="dashed") + 
geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(x)),linetype="dashed") + 
scale_color_manual(labels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), values = c("gold3","forestgreen","blue","firebrick3")) + 
guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 4)))
```

and the output is

[image: four quadrant chart]

The question is if I only want to label the cars randomly for within each quadrant, what should I do? Furthermore, due to the fact that the numbers of cars are different in each quadrant what if I want to label them proportional to the numbers of each quadrant? The more the points, the more the labeled.

The fact is if I turn to a rather large dataset with many more data points with a trick setting of `max.overlaps` and `size` within `geom_text_repel` then only some of the points are labeled but this is not what I want. Or I could randomly generate a new variable as the labeling indicator, say 1 to be labeled and 0 otherwise? Yet I further wish the labels are scattered reasonably, i.e., not crowded with a small region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply generate a new data frame where you remove a proportion of the records per class and use this as `data` argument in `geom_text_repel`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

my_data <- mtcars %>% 
   mutate(class = case_when(
      mpg >= mean(mpg) & drat >= mean(drat) ~ 1,
      mpg < mean(mpg) & drat >= mean(drat) ~ 2,
      mpg < mean(mpg) & drat < mean(drat) ~ 3,
      mpg >= mean(mpg) & drat < mean(drat) ~ 4
   ) %>% factor()) %>% 
   tibble::rownames_to_column("model")
my_data_sample <- my_data %>% 
   slice_sample(prop = -.5, by = class) ## remove 50% of the data in each group
my_data %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = drat, color = class)) + 
   geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(mpg)),linetype = "dashed") + 
   geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(drat)),linetype = "dashed") + 
   geom_point(size = 2) +
   geom_text_repel(aes(label = model), max.overlaps = 12, size = 4,
                   data = my_data_sample) + 
   scale_color_manual(labels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), 
                      values = c("gold3","forestgreen","blue","firebrick3")) +
   ggtitle("four quadrant chart") + 
   theme_classic() + 
   theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 20, face = "bold"), 
         axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1, vjust = 1, size = 10),
         axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10),
         axis.title.x = element_text(size = 20),
         axis.title.y = element_text(size = 20), 
         legend.position = c(0.9, 0.15), 
         legend.title = element_blank(), 
         legend.text = element_text(size = 15))
```

[image: Scatterplot of mpg vs drat where only half the points are labeled]

*N.B.* Some dots have exact same coordinates, hence it seems that the proportion of labeled points does not correspond to `50%` but you can easily verify that this is indeed the case:

```r
my_data %>% 
  count(class)

#   class  n
# 1     1 13
# 2     2  5
# 3     3 13
# 4     4  1

my_data_sample %>% 
  count(class)

#   class n
# 1     1 7
# 2     2 3
# 3     3 7
# 4     4 1
```